# How to cope with "Unresponsive Script" popups controling Firefox with watir-webdriver

Tags: firefox, selenium, popup, watir-webdriver

This popup kills many of my tests.  Even simple DOM interactions like .exists? timeout.  Is there any way of detecting that it appeared and dismissing it?

```
Warning: Unresponsive script.

A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.
```

> dom.max_script_run_time=999
>
> dom.max_chrome_script_run_time=19

These websites aren't designed nor influenced by me. I am merely scraping and sending them instructions as customer.

Answer (score 1):

I run a small autoit3 application that kills popups. If I recall correctly, it waits a little bit to see if the popup is handled before it kills it. This removed many frustrations for me. I also had a version of this that would match certain keywords in the title or body that was read from a file - that allowed me to avoid killing something that needed to stay.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;   AutoIt Version:     3.1.0                                               ;
;   Author:             Dave McNulla                                        ;
;   Script Function:    Close unwanted popups during test automation.       ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


Opt("GUIOnEventMode", 1)  ; Change to OnEvent mode
Opt("WinTextMatchMode", 1)  ;0=best, 1=quick
Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 2)     ;1=start, 2=subStr, 3=exact, 4=advanced
Opt("TrayIconHide", 0) ;0=show, 1=hide
Opt("TrayMenuMode", 0) ;0=default
TraySetIcon("Shell32.dll", 98)

dim $SleepTime = 2000
dim $Max = 100

$Message = "{ENTER}"
$ButtonClick = "[CLASS:Button; TEXT:OK]"
$Title = "[CLASS:#32770;TITLE:Internet Explorer]"

While 1
    If WinExists($Title) Then
        WinActivate($Title)
        Sleep($SleepTime)
        ControlClick($Title, "", $ButtonClick)
    EndIf
    Sleep($SleepTime)
    If $Max < 1 Then Exit(1)
WEnd
```

Comment: +1 for code. My Ruby stuff runs under Ubuntu Linux, where there is a myriad of more native UI automators for that matter, though AutoIt could be supported by Wine.  However sometimes my webdriving jobs get sent off to a Selenium grid for speedup, in which case I may not even know which PC (nor OS) will actually run the web browser.  BTW in Windows I've been a fan of AutoHotKey instead.  Does AutoIt also let you compile into .exe?

Comment: There is probably a solution for each platform that can be implemented - that would help your grid solution. AutoIt3 does create executables and they are quite small. It has saved my bacon a few times. If you want, I could share my dropbox folder of autoit scripts.

Comment: I found this python tool (but I have never used Python) that can be used on linux:  http://ldtp.freedesktop.org/wiki/Docs - I have seen similar for Mac OS X: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/atomac - and of course Windows http://www.tizmoi.net/watsup/intro.html

Comment: Thanks--if you share the dropbox I'll take a gander

Comment: DB requires I send you a 'Share' by email. SO doesn't seem to provide your email addy. Sorry. Like two strangers passing in the night (I mean DropBox and StackOverflow)

Comment: stackoverflow.com@askmarcos.com Ahh thanks, I didn't realize it was invisible and can't seem to find any option to toggle that. Maybe cuz I use OpenID? hmm